# How to find if a set of type pair contains an element as the second member?

Tags: c++, stl, set, std-pair

If I have a set of following type :

`std::set<std::pair<double,unsigned> > X;`

and I want to find the location of the first occurrence of `unsigned y` which would be the second member in the `std::set X`.

How can I do it efficiently?

TIA

Comment: What do you mean by "first" and "second" in this context, given that sets are unordered?

Comment: In my set first member would be of type double and second member would be of type unsigned

Comment: So you're trying to find a set item whose `.second` item is the same as some other unsigned value?

Comment: yes, that's what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::find_if` with a predicate.

```
int main() {
  std::set<std::pair<double,unsigned>> X { {1.1, 1}, {2.2, 2}, {3.3, 3} };
  unsigned valToSearch = 2;

  // the searah method with predicate:
  auto it = std::find_if(X.begin(), X.end(),
     [valToSearch](const std::pair<double,unsigned>& elem) {return elem.second == valToSearch;});

  if(it != X.end())
    std::cout << it->first << ", " << it->second;

  return 0;
}
```

**Output**

> 2.2, 2

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not sure what did you mean by cbegin and cend. If I would want to iterate through the whole set X, and would want to find out unsigned y would this be the right way to do it:

auto it = std::find_if( x.begin(), X.end(),    
[y](const auto& elem) { return elem.second == y; }

Comment: If I do this I get an error saying "unable to resolve identifier second"